# Yiddish city name from the 19th c

Tags: geography, history

There is a locale referenced in a few places in stories or other materials relating to R' Y'chi'el Tz'vi Margaliyos called טאקאלא, on which extremely little information seems to be available online. (For example, see the last paragraph [here](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_28732_19.pdf).)

Is it a city, a province, a region, etc.? Where is it and what modern location does it correspond to? Is there a specific paper source I could look to for information like this?

Comment: Try contacting the researchers at Yad Vashem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked it up on [JewishGen](http://www.jewishgen.org/)'s Shtetl Search. The closest match seems to be Tuchola, western Poland (formerly part of Germany), about 100 miles NE of Poznan (Posen).

Answer (score 1):

I noticed mention of Karlin in the letters your link pointed to. Perhaps that region is a good start for your search. Or ask a Karliner Chosid who is knowledgeable of their history.

Stolin is the main branch of Karlin and they are in Brooklyn and E.Y., but in E.Y. there are also Pinsk/Karlin, Karlin/Lelov and one other branch that I cannot recall its name.